# how to 2 lists in 1 foreach statements

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf

I have 2 Lists which contains textboxes and comboboxes.
Here the textboxes and comboboxes are created:

```
System.Windows.Controls.TextBox newTxt = new TextBox();
System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox newcombo = new ComboBox();
// Add Textbox
newTxt.Text = col.Field<String>("ColumnName");
newTxt.Name = col.Field<String>("ColumnName");
newTxt.Width = 110;

// Add Combobox
newcombo.Items.Add(myReader.GetDataTypeName(n));
newcombo.Items.Add("INT");
newcombo.SelectedItem = myReader.GetDataTypeName(n);
newcombo.Name = myReader.GetDataTypeName(n);
newcombo.Width = 90;
```

And here i create the two lists:

```
List<TextBox> textboxes = sp.Children.OfType<TextBox>().ToList();
List<ComboBox> comboboxes = sp.Children.OfType<ComboBox>().ToList();
```

Now I want a MySQL Query to edit a column. So I need the ColumnName (textbox.Name) and the DataType (combobox.SelectedItem)
I need a foreach for this:

```
foreach (var count in textboxes)
{
    var selected = "i dont know";
    config conf = new config();
    db_connection();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE firmenkunden CHANGE COLUMN " + count.Name + " " + count.Text + " " + selected  + " NOT NULL";
    MessageBox.Show(cmd.CommandText);
}
```

for the textboxes i can get the name with count.Name and the text of the textbox with count.Text. But How I get the .SelectedItem from combobox in this foreach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have same number of textboxes and combo boxes, you can iterate thru lists using indexes, like this:

```
for (int i=0; i< textboxes.Count; i++)
{
    //with i you can access specific textbox from one list and combo from another
    var tb = textboxes[i];
    var cb = comboboxes[i];
}
```

Comment: sorry, i have edited my answer, it should be `for (int i=0; i< textboxes.Count; i++)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try one list with type UserControl. Sinds Textbox and Combobox inherit from UserControl.

And the only properties you use are: Name and Text these are properties come from the base UserControl.

```
 // Add Textbox
 TextBox newTxt = new TextBox();
 newTxt.Text = col.Field<String>("ColumnName");
 newTxt.Name = col.Field<String>("ColumnName");
 newTxt.Width = 110;

 // Add Combobox
 ComboBox newcombo = new ComboBox();
 newcombo.Items.Add(myReader.GetDataTypeName(n));
 newcombo.Items.Add("INT");
 newcombo.SelectedItem = myReader.GetDataTypeName(n);
 newcombo.Name = myReader.GetDataTypeName(n);
 newcombo.Width = 90;

 controls.Add(newcombo);
 controls.Add(newTxt);


 var controls = sp.Children.OfType<UserControl>().ToList();

 foreach (var control in controls )
 {
    var selected = "i dont know";
    config conf = new config();
    db_connection();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE firmenkunden CHANGE COLUMN " + control.Name + " " + control .Text + " " + selected  + " NOT NULL";
    MessageBox.Show(cmd.CommandText);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a 1:1 relation of `TextBoxes` and `ComboBoxes`, you should reflect that relation in your code to ensure you get the values you expect.  Either with something like a `Dictionary` if you know the values for the textboxes are unique:

```
Dictionary<string, object> d = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

wherein your `Value` should be replaced with the `combobox` value type, and your `textbox` string should be the `Key`, then your loop is this:

```
    foreach (var de in d)
                {
                    var selected = "i dont know";
                    config conf = new config();
                    db_connection();
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
                    cmd.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE firmenkunden CHANGE COLUMN "
                    + d.Key + " " + d.Value + " " + selected  + " NOT NULL";
                    MessageBox.Show(cmd.CommandText);
                }
```

or a `private` nested `class` made to handle the relation:

```
private class Strings
{   
    public string A {get;set;}
    public string B {get;set;}
    public Strings(TextBox a, ComboBox b)
    {
       this.A = a.Name; this.B = b.SelectedValue.ToString();
    }
}
```

and then set like this:

```
List<Strings> x = new List<strings>();
x.add(new Strings(textboxcontrol, combocontrol))
```

and then retrieved by:

```
foreach (var o in x)
                {
                    var selected = "i dont know";
                    config conf = new config();
                    db_connection();
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
                    cmd.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE firmenkunden CHANGE COLUMN " 
                    + o.A + " " + o.B + " " + selected  + " NOT NULL";
                    MessageBox.Show(cmd.CommandText);
                }
```

I would recommend better variable and class names, I was just responding quickly :)